# How to allocate a chunk of memory using known address in pure C, not C++

Tags: c, memory

The question is in the topic name. How to allocate a memory using known address? In c++ we could use placement form of `operator new(std::size_t, void* p)`. How can it be done in pure `c`?

Comment: No need to allocate: `void *address = 0xDEADBEEF; memmove(address, main, 100);` (you may need to ignore compiler warnings)

Comment: Makes no sense.  C++ requires this syntax in order to call the constructor.  C doesn't have any.  Just party on the pointer directly, typically after casting it.

Comment: There is no allocation in C++ placement-new. If you want to use memory that is *valid*, there's an operator for that: `&`. Or some *valid* pointer math from some other *valid* address. Otherwise your question is unclear, the title misleading (if in fact you do not desire to allocate *anything* and just want to start using a some hacked-in numeric value as an "address").

Answer (score 7):

The C++'s *placement-new* operator allocates the *object* within given address (not the memory itself), and calls its constructor.

> *How to allocate a memory using known address?*

It is not a *memory-allocation* then. You either already have the memory allocated (and you **know** the address of a valid location), or not at all (then you don't have the address, or the address is not *valid*).

Assuming you already have the address of a pre-allocated memory chunk, you are already allowed to use it:

```
struct MyStruct { int x; };

void* my_address = ...; // known and already allocated chunk of memory, e.g.
                        // - from stack: char mem[sizeof(MyStruct)]; -> mem
                        // - from heap:  malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
                        // - any location that can be considered `valid'

struct MyStruct* my_struct = my_address;
my_struct->x = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, best to remove that cast. Anyone would think you're writing C++. But I'm worried about what was omitted in the "...".

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use memory at a known address in C is as follows.

```
struct s { unsigned a; }; /* structure presumed to exist at some known location */
unsigned int loc = 0x100; /* address in known memory */
struct s* ploc = (struct s*)loc;  /* cast to any pointer - see below */
s->a = 0;  /* zap it */
```

See n1570 S6.3.2.3/7

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

No allocation is necessary. Just use it. But don't get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int buffer[3] = {0};
  int *address;

  printf("Address of middle element is %p.\n", (void*)(buffer + 1));
  printf("Enter address to assign to (try the value above +/- %d): ", (int)sizeof (int));
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf("%p", (void**)&address);
  *address = 42;
  printf("buffer contents: %d, %d, %d.\n", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2]);
  return 0;
}
```